# Company name search yields many related results but no home page

Tags: seo, query-string, google-search

I'm trying to resolve an "issue": if I google for the keyword that is my website's domain (just the company name), I get a lot of results related to the company except for the home page... here is the output I see in the first 10 pages (I didn't look further).
- Crunchbase page
- Linkedin page
- Facebook page
- Our zendesk help center page
- Some external blog references on VentureBeat, pocketgamer, Forbes, etc

The site is accessible with or without www. prefix. The site is also accessible on http and https. It is a wordpress powered website.

Here is the [google URL of the query](https://www.google.co.il/#q=trophit)

I've then tried googling for 'site:trophit.com' according to google's recommendation when your website doesn't show up on searches. Interesting enough - I get results of some posts in my website but NOT PAGES. Here is [that query as well](https://www.google.co.il/#q=site:trophit.com)

I browsed some pages that are missing from the search and found that they contain the following metadata:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
```

I checked the Wordpress->settings->reading section, the "discourage robots" is unchecked. I am unaware of any other similar settings in WP.

Any idea why all pages have 'noindex'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: John, problem is I really don't know, could also be a wordpress configuration/code change required, etc.

Comment: Seems like a config problem indeed - not SEO, I've updated the question with the details, I see 'noindex' on pages, not on posts.

Comment: Deactivated the "Easy Digital Downloads" WP plugin, which, after scanning all site php code, was the reason my pages were being injected with "noindex,nofollow". Now I just need to wait a few weeks to see if it helped...